# Taurus / performance tests: verify data inside a JsonArray

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, taurus

I extract a JsonArray containing a list of string, and I want to validate by a regex each string inside this object.
Problem, I don't seem to find any answers on the Taurus' website.
Do you know how I can do it ?
Example below:

```
# Verification of value inside the JsonArray
    extract-jsonpath:
      names: $.names
  - foreach: name in names
    do:
    - jsonpath: ${name} # if this JSONPATH is not found, assert will fail
      validate: true # validate against an expected value
      expected-value: "\\w" # value we're expecting to validate. [default: false]
      regexp: true  # if the value is regular expression, default: true
      expect-null: false  # expected value is null
      invert: false # invert condition
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible with [Taurus YAML syntax](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config) as:

1. `foreach` keyword generates a normal [JMeter ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)
2. These `jsonpath`, `validate`, etc. are applied to a [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) by default, they will not work if you add them just as children of the ForEach Controller

Assuming above points I would suggest adding a [JSR223 PostProcesssor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to perform all the checks. In Taurus it is being done via [JSR223 Blocks](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JSR223-Blocks) like:

```
- url: https://api.example.com/v1/media/search
  extract-jsonpath:
    names: $.names
  jsr223:'1.upto(vars.get("names_matchNr") as int,{if (vars.get("names_$it").matches("\\w+")) {prev.setSuccessful(false)}})'
```

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article to get more ideas with regards to what can be done using Groovy scripts.